# How to add swipe to change between tabs

Tags: angularjs-directive, onsen-ui

I am working on a html5 mobile app project. I found that Onsen ui is very use full and started working on It .

Now I want to swipe between tabs like native android ui .please help

I made tab as this

```
<ons-tabbar position="top" >
    <ons-tab page="page1.html" label="Mobile"  active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="page2.html" label="DTH"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="page3.html" label="Datacard"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

But how to add swipe to change between tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onsen UI doesn't have this feature. It includes the Hammer library to detect gestures, so you could listen to the `drag` event and switch tabs when the user drags left and right.

Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('ons-tabbar:init', function(event) {
  var tabbar = event.component,
      el = tabbar._element[0],
      nbrOfTabs = 4;

  var hammer = new Hammer(el);
  // Bind some events
  hammer.on('drag', function(event) {
        var dx = event.gesture.deltaX,
        idx = tabbar.getActiveTabIndex(),
        th = el.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;

    if (dx > th && idx !== -1) {
      event.gesture.stopDetect();
      tabbar.setActiveTab(Math.max(idx - 1, 0));
    }
    else if (dx < -th && idx !== -1) {
      event.gesture.stopDetect();
      tabbar.setActiveTab(Math.min(idx + 1, nbrOfTabs - 1));
    }
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/vELYaK

Comment: Well, it doesn't show any slide animation so it might not be very useful. Just shows how you can switch tabs by a drag gesture. Sorry about the confusion.